# Pdftex cannot run on FreeBSD

Tags: pdftex, freebsd

I need to run texlive2015 on FreeBSD, so I downloaded it from TUG and installed it.
Then I tried running pdftex and tex, but both get the error message: I can't find the format file "xxx".

[image]
So is there some environment variable missing? I have tried installing texlive to /usr/local and also tried a local directory.

Comment: The canonical way to install things on FreeBSD is via `pkg` package manager.

Comment: why 2015 now, not 2020?